# How do I make FlashDevelop the default IDE for Adobe Flash Professional?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, ide, adobe, flashdevelop

How do I make FlashDevelop the default IDE for Adobe Flash Professional?  So that if I try to open an .as file from Adobe Flash Professional, it opens in FlashDevelop instead?

I am coming from Unity where there is just an option in preferences to set your default IDE, but I am struggling to figure it out here in Adobe Flash Professional.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via Windows.

1. Right-click on any `.as` file
2. Click "Open with..."
3. Click "Browse..."
4. Navigate to your install folder (`C:\Program Files (x86)\FlashDevelop`), and select "FlashDevelop.exe"
5. Click "Open" to select FlashDevelop.exe
6. Make sure that "Always use the selected program to open this kind of file" is checked
7. Click "OK"

From now on, ActionScript files will open in FlashDevelop.

**NOTE**: If you have multi-instance mode turned on, a new instance of FlashDevelop will run every time you open an `.as` file from Windows Explorer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he means how to launch FlashDevelop from Flash Pro (for example, right-click a library symbol and edit class), not *.as file association in Windows.

Comment: You are correct; I misunderstood the question. After scouring Flash's settings panel (what little there is of it), it doesn't appear to be possible. If Flash Builder is installed on the same system, you can tell Flash to open class files using Flash Builder, but I don't see a way to add FlashDevelop to the list of editors.